# react-hooks/exhaustive-deps vs testing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing

In our codebase, we like to use a factory function for hooks like `useEffect` because it allows us to more easily test the effect. I'm sure this worked nicely in the past with [react-hooks/exhaustive-deps](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html), but now - it seems like it no longer traces dependencies through the factory function:

```
const effect = (name: string) => () => {
  console.log("hello", name);
};

function App() {
  const [name, setName] = React.useState("alice");

  // this one isn't caught
  React.useEffect(effect(name), []);

  // this one is
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("hello", name);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {name}
      <button
        onClick={() =>
          setName((oldName) => (oldName === "alice" ? "bob" : "alice"))
        }
      >
        toggle
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here's a codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-varahamihira-qwz8m?file=/src/App.js:200-350

What would be a good alternative approach that would still allow us to test the code for `effect` in an isolated way?

Comment: Are you sure it's disallowed? The rules of hooks haven't changed since release, so I'm curious here. I also tried this in a codesandbox (lints hooks out-of-the-box, react/react-dom 16.13.1 and react-scripts 3.4.1) and it doesn't complain at all.

Comment: Hm, you're right. On codesandbox, I'm not able to reproduce the initial problem. We're not using CRA though, so I think it might be a versioning issue. I have a different issue on codesandbox though - I've updated the question accordingly.